# WebIOPi no connection with I2C device alert

Tags: arduino, communication, webiopi

I am working with WebIOPi on a Raspberry Pi 2. The raspberry is connected to an Arduino Nano via I2C (Python script working well with the Nano - a button from a web page can turn on or off LEDs).

Is it possible to make a diagnostic Javascript alert when the connection with the Arduino is broken (if line/wire I2C is broken)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solved in low level (python script + return some value). 
Example python script:

```
try:
    bus.write_byte(address, int(value))
    time.sleep(0.01)
    number = bus.read_byte(address)
    flag = number
except IOError:
    number = 11 #error value (my fantasy)
    flag = number
```

"flag" variable used in javascript to recognize connection status and if flag = 11 then comes alert("no connection")